# reading Bloomberg data using blpapi in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, bloomberg

trying to read Bloomberg data in Google Colab (have been using Bloomberg data in python via anaconda for a while). any ideas how to load it in the Colab environment? ^Thank you very much!

!python -m pip install --index-url=https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple blpapi

shows the following

```
Looking in indexes: https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple
Collecting blpapi
  Downloading https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple/blpapi/blpapi-3.14.0.tar.gz (221kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 3.7MB/s 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Can you post the log content?

Comment: sure - i am too new to these -how can I see the log content for this one? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can download it straight from the URL provided but google Collab provides a Bloomberg Open API in itself.

(command: !pip install pdblp)

(documented here: https://pypi.org/project/pdblp/)